# Ignoring letters and parsing only numbers using Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

This code works only when numerals (eg: `"1243\t343\n"`) are present:

```
tabFile = endBy line eol
line = sepBy cell (many1 tab)
cell = integer
eol = char '\n'

integer = rd <$> many digit
  where rd = read :: String -> Int
```

Is there a way to make it parse `"abcd\tefg\n1243\t343\n"` such that it ignores the `"abcd\tefg\n"` part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip everything except digits using [skipMany](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.3/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3askipMany). Something like the next:

```
many (skipMany (noneOf ['0'..'9']) >> digit)
```

or (depending on what you actually need)

```
skipMany (noneOf ['0'..'9']) >> many digit
```

Answer (score 1):

So the trick is to modify integers to simply skip letters.

```
integer :: Parser Int
integer =
  many letter *>
  ((read . concat) <$> many digit `sepBy` many1 letter)
  <* many letter
```

This handles `12a34` correctly. Otherwise something as easy as

```
 many letter *> (read <$> many digit) <* many letter
```